# Reassign onclick for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a problem with `<a>` tags.

I need to reassign an `onclick` event to this tag, but the `href` attribute must contain a link.

For example, I have some link:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
```

And i need to change only the `onclick` event for this link so that when I click on it, some JavaScript function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to return false in 'onclick', or browser will handle click and open link in href.

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" onclick="yourfunction(this); return false;" >Wikipedia</a>
```

Comment: that will only call the function but won't redirect to en.wikipedia.org i think

Comment: He didn't say he needs redirect :-)

Comment: Yes, that's right, i don't need redirect:) That was the problem)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean, but try this:

```
$(function() {
    // Find all links pointing to wikipedia
    $("a[href*='wikipedia.org']").click(function() {
        // Do something
        return false; // to prevent the link from actually going to wikipedia
    });
});
```

Comment: using jquery to change onclick handler for single link is overkill

Answer (score 0):

> but href attribute must contain a link

If you provide a link then the page will be redirected there, so you might want to do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="func1();func2();redirect('url');">Wikipedia</a>
```

This makes sure that you perform your functions first and finally `redirect` function to redirect the page to the url you specify.

Comment: Inline javascript is bad. http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: @Tatu: you are right but i did not want the newbie to make it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to give your link an id, ie

```
<a href="http://wikipedia.org" id="myLink">Whatever</a>
```

Then simply assign an onclick via jquery like so:

```
$("a#myLink").click(function() {
   //Go wild! 

});
```